# How to query from an existing table in sqlite with sequelize

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sequelize.js

Going through the documentation in sequelize, I get pretty simplistic way of creating a table and populating it. However, when querying data from a table, the examples they give are tied to the model you just defined previously. What I want is flexibility to obtain data from a table, even if it was created in another file, or created elsewhere. In normal mysql or sqlite, if you go to say phpmyadmin or other GUIs for mysql or sqlite, you can create a database, and a table, then in your code, come and select * from that table and it works fine. I wanted similar flexibility here with sequelize. Create a table graphically using some other GUI app, and maybe even populate that table, then in my javascript code come and select * from that existing table. How do I do this with sqlite with sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the sequelize library is just an interface to the database server just like the GUI tool you mentioned. You can just install a GUI tool (mySQLWorkbench etc), point it to the host address of the database server(Local or remote), pre-populate it with the data you want and code your queries in nodejs ...after you have defined your sequelize schemas of course :)